# problem in checking for email registration

Tags: java

In this example I want to check if eMail is registered or not. The function `checkDuplicateEmail.emailCheck(emailcounter, email)` will check the condition and return the `boolean` value. If the value is not true then it is supposed to insert the data but unfortunately it's not happening. Only in case eMail is matched the the else part is executing.

```java
PreparedStatement st1 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM customer where email = ?");
st1.setString(1,email);
ResultSet rs = st1.executeQuery();
checkDuplicateEmail checkDuplicateEmail = new checkDuplicateEmail();
while(rs.next()) {
    emailcounter = rs.getString("email");
    boolean isValid = checkDuplicateEmail.emailCheck(emailcounter, email);
}
    if(!isValid) {
        System.out.println("Email is Exists");
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("insert into customer(name, email, mobileno, username, password) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        st.setString(1, name); //substituting ? with actual value
        st.setString(2, email);
        st.setInt(3, mobileNo);
        st.setString(4, username);
        String encoded = enc.encodeToString(password.getBytes());
        st.setString(5, encoded);
        st.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Email is already Exists");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("<html><body>");
        out.write("<h1>Registration cannot be sucessful because email is already registered!</h1>");
        out.write("</body></html>");
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: _it's not happening_ does not tell me what the problem is. Is this line (from the code in your question) executing? `System.out.println("Email is Exists");` If it is, then is an exception being thrown by any of the code following that line? If no exception is thrown, then are you saying that a row is not being added to [database] table `customer`?

Comment: `checkDuplicateEmail.emailCheck` does it returns true or false, please have a look

Comment: By the way: What is the code of class `checkDuplicateEmail`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thankyou guys for the solutions , actually i made a silly mistake , ie i'm writing my if-else code inside while loop , it's supposed written outside the while loop.

Comment: @Reporter checkDuplicateEmail is another class in which i wrote a function to checkduplicates for email id in the database

Comment: @AshishPatil yes it returns true / false

Comment: @Community in this code i want to check if email id of a user is registered in the database , if yes then the user data should not be inserted in the database , my code is working now anyways

Comment: @AbhishekDwivedi Either you check the code of `checkDuplicateEmail` by iyour self or provide this code. By the way: Classnames must be started with a capitalized letter.